# Connection close if its idle for certain time

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, .net-4.5, tcpserver

I have Client – Server application implemented in .Net 4.5, everything works Fine.

Multiple clients (Hardware devices) are connected to server concurrently and data transfer occurs.

Now I want to close the connection from server if no data transfer happens for certain time  period on socket i.e. I simply want to close the connection from server,  if it remains idle  (No data transfer occurs ) for let’s say 5 Min.

Comment: Should already work. In fact, trying to get the socket to stay open, usually requires the client to periodically send a "KeepAlive" packet.

Comment: What classes do you use?

Comment: @DieterMeemken Its simply under System.net & Systsem.net.socket namespace with TCPListner class

Answer (score 1):

I think you can implement something like this:

```
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Now;

using (var client = new HttpClient)
{
    DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    while(currentDateTime - startDateTime < threshold)
    {
        currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        if(dataArrive)
        {
           startDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    //TO DO: Close communication channel
}
```

Where threshold is your 5 Min. and //dataArrive is true when data transfer occurs.

Instead, you do an http request you can use the HttpClient.Timeout property.

Comment: Your solutions seems good let me give try on it, I am using TCPListner, and i wonder if there is some timeout propoerty exist in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You have explore the option to set proper value for idle_timeout parameter that takes care closing the connection once it reached the threshold.

Comment: Is there anything like Idle_timeout property? Will you please elaborate on it

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement connection timeouts at the application level (as a part of your communication protocol): for each connection, after you receive data, start a **timer** set to predefined timeout value (e.g. 5 minutes). If you receive data before timeout, reset the timer. If you don't receive the data, stop the timer and close that connection.